# How to logout and signin with another facebook account

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, logout

I use the facebook app's `SingleSignOn` dialog to login, but I can't clear the cache of the facebook app.
So when I try to use another facebook account to login, it will login automatically with the previous account.

What can I do ?

```
public String logout(Context context) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Util.clearCookies(context);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");
    String response = request(b);
    setAccessToken(null);
    setAccessExpires(0);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AsyncRunner.logout()` method. Take a look at [example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#logout).